# Is there an option for translate to SVF viewer using Design Automation API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Im just looking if is possible to create an SVF Viewer using Design Automation API and avoiding Model Derivative API.
Months ago I had a talk with the Forge support team and they told me that due to the amount of translates, for an economic issue it was convenient for me to use Design Automation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SVF translation on Design Automation API is not supported currently as I was told, except for AutoCAD. You may use this activity to generate SVF with the Design Automation API for AutoCAD:

```
{
    "commandLine": [
        "$(engine.path)\\accoreconsole.exe /i $(args[HostDwg].path) /al $(appbundles[Publish2View22].path) /s $(settings[script].path) /suppressGraphics"
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "HostDwg": {
            "verb": "get",
            "description": "Host drawing",
            "required": true,
            "localName": "$(HostDwg)"
        },
        "Result": {
            "zip": true,
            "verb": "post",
            "description": "Results",
            "required": true,
            "localName": "result"
        }
    },
    "id": "AutoCAD.AcSvfPublish+prod",
    "engine": "Autodesk.AutoCAD+22",
    "appbundles": [
        "AutoCAD.Publish2View22+prod"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "script": {
            "value": "(command \"_prepareforpropertyextraction\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_indexextractor\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_publishtosvf\" \"./output/result.svf\")\n(command \"_createbubblepackage\" \"./output\" \"./result\" \"\" \"\")\n"
        }
    },
    "description": "AutoCAD translation sample generating SVF via core console.",
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3ds Max engine also support generating svf file(s).  You should be able to easily write a script to export to svf and execute it in Design Automation.

See this documentation on how to export in maxscript:

https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-624D3D05-B15D-4A97-9F15-DA35CDB0DDD2#GUID-624D3D05-B15D-4A97-9F15-DA35CDB0DDD2__SECTION_EB566E2CC6444FCEAD2EE67BB366F727

See this tutorial on how to execute a script in Design Automation for 3ds Max:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/3dsmax/